# how Sorting a nested array?

Tags: php

I need a standard function for sorting. I don't want to use loops etc.

Array

Before sorting

```
$arr = [
    [5, 7, 1, 4],
    [88, 43, 56],
    [12, 64, 3],
];
```

after sorting I want to get

```
$arr = [
    [1, 4, 5, 7],
    [43, 56, 88],
    [3, 12, 64],
];
```

I know as do it. I don't like this way. I am looking for a standard function without loops.

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [5, 7, 1, 4],
    [88, 43, 56],
    [12, 64, 3],
];

foreach ($arr as $k => &$innersArr) {
    usort($innersArr, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a - $b;
    });
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What's the sorting criteria?

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the "outer" array always stay the same? Do you only want to sort the "inner arrays"?

Comment: @NicoHaase You only need to sort nested arrays. Compare as numbers. The external sorting level is not important.

Comment: @sekthor The external sorting level is not important. I need only inner arrays

Comment: use `sort()` on every nested array

Comment: @ciekals11 I want to get by with a standard function, no loop.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function that will do that. You need a loop.

Comment: @Barmar I have about 10 years of experience in php. And for the first time I wondered if this could be done without a loop.

Comment: Check `array_multisort()`. It has lots of powerful features, maybe this is one of them.

Comment: or use `array_map()` and in callback provide function that will return sorted array

Comment: Please share what you've tried to resolve the problem. Anything wrong with `array_map`? Anything wrong with using a loop (that would help to keep your code readable)?

Comment: @Barmar i can this function. I can't sort the array in question with it. In the documentation of the function, an example with a loop

Comment: I said maybe. I didn't really think it could.

Comment: If any attempt is not working, please add it to your question such that others can check your code

Comment: @NicoHaase I add work code. I have added working code to the question. And you can see the result. I want to do the same with a standard function without a loop

Comment: @ciekals11 I have added working code to the question. And you can see the result. I want to do the same with a standard function without a loop

Comment: And what have you tried to avoid the loop? If you state that `array_map` and `array_multisort` do not work, why not share the code you've used for these attempts?

Comment: @Pramod Singh posted answer that I had in mind and it works just like you wanted it to. Without loop.

Comment: Well, even if there is no `foreach` loop, this uses something like that internally ;)

Comment: Even if you will find a method that will do it with one line there will be a loop somewhere. You have to iterate this element because you don't know how many elements it have. If you know how many element it have then you can use `sort($arr[0]);sort($arr[1]);sort($arr[2]);sort($arr[3]);`, but  `sort` has a loop inside of it as well. Most of sorting algorithms in php uses [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) which from definition uses loop to check every element of given array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_map and sort functions.

```
<?php
function mySort($a){
sort($a);
return $a;
}
$sortedArray = array_map('mySort',$arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sortedArray);
?>
```

Comment: No bad, thanks,  I thought there was one common function